# Reliably read value of PHP display_errors

Tags: error-handling, php

In my PHP error handler I want to do something like:

```
if (ini_get('display_errors') IS ON)) {
 // show debug info
} else {
 // show just "oops!"
}
```

I've look through the docs and stuff, but I can't really find out what the possible values for display_errors are (such as "on", 0, "Yes") and what it does for what value.

What should I put in place of the "IS ON" to reliably read this value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the string representation of the values through [**ini_get()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php), values that `display_errors` can be set to is either, `true\false`, `0\1` and `On\Off`. But when user's set their `php.ini` it is more common to use `1` or `On`

```
if (ini_get('display_errors') == "1") {
 // show debug info
}
```

or to check for *ALL* cases, you can perform a switch-case

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
switch (ini_get('display_errors')) {
  case "1":
  case "On":
  case "true":
    // show debug info
}
```

If you prefer the equality comparison approach, notice that `ini_get` returns a `String` value of `1`, if you test the returned value with `ini_get` using the `==` with the `int` value `1`, it becomes true. If you use the `===` it checks if both are equal and of the same type. `String` is not the same type as `int` so it would return `false`.

```
1 == "1"; // in PHP, this returns true, it doesn't check the type.
1 ===  "1"; // would be false, this however checks the type.
```

Using `ini_get('display_errors')` you can check against values like, `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and
even `NULL`. They will return a boolean value of either `0` which is `false` and anything other than `0` evaluates to `true`.

```
if (2) {
 echo "2 is true!"; // echos "2 is true!"
}
```

I saw your comment about a discrepancy so I decided to test it myself, here is what I used

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  $verbose = ini_get('display_errors');
  echo $verbose; // echo's 1

  // just to test its return values.
  if ($verbose) { 
     echo "verbose is true";  // echos "verbose is true"
  }

  ini_set('display_errors', 0);
  $verbose = ini_get('display_errors');
  echo $verbose; // echo's 0

  if ($verbose) {
     echo "verbose is not true"; // does not get evaluated
  }
?>
```

This answer is a bit lengthy, but I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Technically it is a string, and some people set it to 'on' . So while you could just check if it is equal to 1, this won't work if you are working in a weird environment. Thus making it not reliable.

Comment: Too simple. >> ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); $verbose = ini_get('display_errors') == 1; << Verbose is now false, despite the "On".

Comment: It's set to On in php.ini but when you call `ini_get` it returns 1, whether its a string or an int

Comment: I didn't know that until I read the documentation from my link, its one of the examples

Comment: Thanks for the expansion, but about the discrepancy: You did not yet test setting it to 'On', which is what I did. Never mind though, I'm just checking for true and "On" now. If people set anything else, their fault it breaks.

Comment: I edited it yesterday with a switch-case to show all the values, which tests for either, `1`, `On` and `true` which are all legitimate values.

Comment: I know this is somewhat old, but display_errors could legally be set to 'Off' or 'off', and in these cases `ini_get()` returns the string 'Off', which as a boolean is true, so testing the value of ini_get() in these two cases wrongly gives an incorrect true result.  The safest and most robust solution seems to be to use `filter_var)()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` as shown in hostingutilities.com's answer below.

Answer (score 6):

I use the following code:

```
if (in_array(strtolower(ini_get('display_errors')), ['1', 'yes', 'on', 'true']) {
  // is enabled
} else {
  // is disabled
}
```

Or regexp

```
if (preg_match('/^(1|yes|on|true)$/i', ini_get('display_errors')) {
  // is enabled
} else {
  // is disabled
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
if ( filter_var( ini_get('display_errors'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ){

}
```

And that should catch all of the different ways display_errors could get turned on ("1", "true", "on", "yes", etc.).

I also can't find any official documentation on this, but from what I've experienced, I believe using `filter_var` with the [FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) flag will cover the full gamut of possible ways an ini setting can be set to true/false.

Comment: Documentation states "Returns true for "1", "true", "on" and "yes". Returns false otherwise.". This is the best answer and future proof.

Comment: This seems to work: `if (filter_var(strtolower(ini_get('display_errors')), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) {`

Answer (score 2):

The default is '1' according to the documentation. However, you might want to check the inverse, that it isn't off:

`!= FALSE` or `!empty()`

```
if (ini_get('display_errors') != FALSE)) 
{
     // show debug info
} 
else 
{
     // show just "oops!"
}
```

Or as Anthony pointed out, you could just check for `1`

```
if(ini_get('display_errors') == 1))
```

You might also want to check `error_reporting`, as it is another common setting that is used to control the displaying of errors, although its meaning is slightly different than `display_errors`

```
if(error_reporting() != 0)
```

Comment: @Chacha102 - `ini_get` returns a String, you were correct. :) but apparently it doesn't matter whether you compare `1` or `"1"`, I guess it just depends on the comparison operator.